# mysqldump produce a corrupted sql file (apparently on tables with stored generated column) (MySQL v8.0.21)

Tags: mysql, database-backups, mysql-backup

I am using MySQL v8.0.21 and mysqldump v8.0.23.

I have a table with the following schema:

```
mysql> desc resource_downloads;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+------------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra            |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+------------------+
| compositeId | varchar(250) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | STORED GENERATED |
| resourceId  | int unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                  |
| userId      | int unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                  |
| fileId      | int unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                  |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+------------------+
```

and the following values:

```
mysql> select * from resource_downloads;
+-------------+------------+--------+--------+
| compositeId | resourceId | userId | fileId |
+-------------+------------+--------+--------+
| 24-150-NULL |         24 |    150 |   NULL |
| 37-150-NULL |         37 |    150 |   NULL |
| 56-150-48   |         56 |    150 |     48 |
| 56-150-NULL |         56 |    150 |   NULL |
+-------------+------------+--------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the SQL statement to create the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `resource_downloads` (`compositeId` varchar(250) AS (CONCAT_WS('-', resourceId, userId, IFNULL(fileId, 'NULL'))) STORED NOT NULL, `resourceId` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `userId` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `fileId` int UNSIGNED NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`compositeId`)) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

When executing the following mysqldump command:

```sh
mysqldump -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWORD $DB_NAME > dump.sql
```

it does produce the following for the `resource_downloads` table:

```sql
--
-- Dumping data for table `resource_downloads`
--

LOCK TABLES `resource_downloads` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `resource_downloads` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `resource_downloads` (`resourceId`, `userId`, `fileId`) VALUES ,24,150,NULL),,24,150,NULL),37,150,NULL),,24,150,NULL),37,150,NULL),56,150,48),,24,150,NULL),37,150,NULL),56,150,48),56,150,NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `resource_downloads` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

which is corrupted as you can see, not a valid SQL statement.

I didn't found anything corresponding to this particular situation and I guess this is due to the generated stored column as it only appears after I introduced it in my db a few days ago.

Is there any workaround to this situation for me to be able to generate a usable dump of my database ? I could think of excluding this table from the dump but this is inconvenient...

Comment: And what's your **programming** related question here?

Comment: There's actually no question at all in this post. It's like a bug report or technical support request. Perhaps you should post it on bugs.mysql.com?

Comment: The bug already exists: [mysqldump creates invalid dumpfile when generated columns exist](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80790)  (as of `18 Mar 2016 13:16` )

Comment: Really sorry, I should have ended my post with a question, which I did just now by editing the post. Thanks a lot @Luuk for the link, I'll check this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the generated column to the end, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `resource_downloads` (
   `resourceId` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
   `userId` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
   `fileId` int UNSIGNED NULL, 
   `compositeId` varchar(250) AS (CONCAT_WS('-', resourceId, userId, IFNULL(fileId, 'NULL'))) STORED NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`compositeId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and not like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `resource_downloads` (
   `compositeId` varchar(250) AS (CONCAT_WS('-', resourceId, userId, IFNULL(fileId, 'NULL'))) STORED NOT NULL, 
   `resourceId` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
   `userId` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
   `fileId` int UNSIGNED NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`compositeId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The mysqldump seems to go OK. (Tested with mysqldump 8.0.25)